# Jquery mobile select option dynamically bulk data?

Tags: android, cordova, jquery-mobile

this is the data i wanted i have added but while seeing in the Android the white screen display on select the issure is that the data is too large if it is out of screen it goes white screen so can anyone help me

```
   <label for="select-choice-min" style="margin-left:10px" class="select">Shipping method:</label> 
    <select name="select-choice-min" id="select-choice-min" data-native-menu="false" data-mini="true"> 
   <option value=""></option> 
                <option value="United States">United States</option> 
                <option value="United Kingdom">United Kingdom</option> 
                <option value="Afghanistan">Afghanistan</option> 
                <option value="Aland Islands">Aland Islands</option> 
                <option value="Albania">Albania</option> 
                <option value="Algeria">Algeria</option> 
                <option value="American Samoa">American Samoa</option> 
                <option value="Andorra">Andorra</option> 
                <option value="Angola">Angola</option> 
                <option value="Anguilla">Anguilla</option> 
                <option value="Antarctica">Antarctica</option> 
                <option value="Antigua and Barbuda">Antigua and Barbuda</option> 
                <option value="Argentina">Argentina</option> 
                <option value="Armenia">Armenia</option> 
                <option value="Aruba">Aruba</option> 
                <option value="Australia">Australia</option> 
                <option value="Austria">Austria</option> 
                <option value="Azerbaijan">Azerbaijan</option> 
                <option value="Bahamas">Bahamas</option> 
                <option value="Bahrain">Bahrain</option> 
                <option value="Bangladesh">Bangladesh</option> 
                <option value="Barbados">Barbados</option> 
                <option value="Belarus">Belarus</option> 
                <option value="Belgium">Belgium</option> 
                <option value="Belize">Belize</option> 
                <option value="Benin">Benin</option> 
                <option value="Bermuda">Bermuda</option> 
                <option value="Bhutan">Bhutan</option> 
                <option value="Bolivia, Plurinational State of">Bolivia, Plurinational State of</option> 
                <option value="Bonaire, Sint Eustatius and Saba">Bonaire, Sint Eustatius and Saba</option> 
                <option value="Bosnia and Herzegovina">Bosnia and Herzegovina</option> 
                <option value="Botswana">Botswana</option> 
                <option value="Bouvet Island">Bouvet Island</option> 
                <option value="Brazil">Brazil</option> 
                <option value="British Indian Ocean Territory">British Indian Ocean Territory</option> 
                <option value="Brunei Darussalam">Brunei Darussalam</option> 
                <option value="Bulgaria">Bulgaria</option> 
                <option value="Burkina Faso">Burkina Faso</option> 
                <option value="Burundi">Burundi</option> 
                <option value="Cambodia">Cambodia</option> 
                <option value="Cameroon">Cameroon</option> 
                <option value="Canada">Canada</option> 
                <option value="Cape Verde">Cape Verde</option> 
                <option value="Cayman Islands">Cayman Islands</option> 
                <option value="Central African Republic">Central African Republic</option> 
                <option value="Chad">Chad</option> 
                <option value="Chile">Chile</option> 
                <option value="China">China</option> 
                <option value="Christmas Island">Christmas Island</option> 
                <option value="Cocos (Keeling) Islands">Cocos (Keeling) Islands</option> 
                <option value="Colombia">Colombia</option> 
                <option value="Comoros">Comoros</option> 
                <option value="Congo">Congo</option> 
                <option value="Congo, The Democratic Republic of The">Congo, The Democratic Republic of The</option> 
                <option value="Cook Islands">Cook Islands</option> 
                <option value="Costa Rica">Costa Rica</option> 
                <option value="Cote D'ivoire">Cote D'ivoire</option> 
                <option value="Croatia">Croatia</option> 
                <option value="Cuba">Cuba</option> 
                <option value="Curacao">Curacao</option> 
                <option value="Cyprus">Cyprus</option> 
                <option value="Czech Republic">Czech Republic</option> 
                <option value="Denmark">Denmark</option> 
                <option value="Djibouti">Djibouti</option> 
                <option value="Dominica">Dominica</option> 
                <option value="Dominican Republic">Dominican Republic</option> 
                <option value="Ecuador">Ecuador</option> 
                <option value="Egypt">Egypt</option> 
                <option value="El Salvador">El Salvador</option> 
                <option value="Equatorial Guinea">Equatorial Guinea</option> 
                <option value="Eritrea">Eritrea</option> 
                <option value="Estonia">Estonia</option> 
                <option value="Ethiopia">Ethiopia</option> 
                <option value="Falkland Islands (Malvinas)">Falkland Islands (Malvinas)</option> 
                <option value="Faroe Islands">Faroe Islands</option> 
                <option value="Fiji">Fiji</option> 
                <option value="Finland">Finland</option> 
                <option value="France">France</option> 
                <option value="French Guiana">French Guiana</option> 
                <option value="French Polynesia">French Polynesia</option> 
                <option value="French Southern Territories">French Southern Territories</option> 
                <option value="Gabon">Gabon</option> 
                <option value="Gambia">Gambia</option> 
                <option value="Georgia">Georgia</option> 
                <option value="Germany">Germany</option> 
                <option value="Ghana">Ghana</option> 
                <option value="Gibraltar">Gibraltar</option> 
                <option value="Greece">Greece</option> 
                <option value="Greenland">Greenland</option> 
                <option value="Grenada">Grenada</option> 
                <option value="Guadeloupe">Guadeloupe</option> 
                <option value="Guam">Guam</option> 
                <option value="Guatemala">Guatemala</option> 
                <option value="Guernsey">Guernsey</option> 
                <option value="Guinea">Guinea</option> 
                <option value="Guinea-bissau">Guinea-bissau</option> 
                <option value="Guyana">Guyana</option> 
                <option value="Haiti">Haiti</option> 
                <option value="Heard Island and Mcdonald Islands">Heard Island and Mcdonald Islands</option> 
                <option value="Holy See (Vatican City State)">Holy See (Vatican City State)</option> 
                <option value="Honduras">Honduras</option> 
                <option value="Hong Kong">Hong Kong</option> 
                <option value="Hungary">Hungary</option> 
                <option value="Iceland">Iceland</option> 
                <option value="India">India</option> 
                <option value="Indonesia">Indonesia</option> 
                <option value="Iran, Islamic Republic of">Iran, Islamic Republic of</option> 
                <option value="Iraq">Iraq</option> 
                <option value="Ireland">Ireland</option> 
                <option value="Isle of Man">Isle of Man</option> 
                <option value="Israel">Israel</option> 
                <option value="Italy">Italy</option> 
                <option value="Jamaica">Jamaica</option> 
                <option value="Japan">Japan</option> 
                <option value="Jersey">Jersey</option> 
                <option value="Jordan">Jordan</option> 
                <option value="Kazakhstan">Kazakhstan</option> 
                <option value="Kenya">Kenya</option> 
                <option value="Kiribati">Kiribati</option> 
                <option value="Korea, Democratic People's Republic of">Korea, Democratic People's Republic of</option> 
                <option value="Korea, Republic of">Korea, Republic of</option> 
                <option value="Kuwait">Kuwait</option> 
                <option value="Kyrgyzstan">Kyrgyzstan</option> 
                <option value="Lao People's Democratic Republic">Lao People's Democratic Republic</option> 
                <option value="Latvia">Latvia</option> 
                <option value="Lebanon">Lebanon</option> 
                <option value="Lesotho">Lesotho</option> 
                <option value="Liberia">Liberia</option> 
                <option value="Libya">Libya</option> 
                <option value="Liechtenstein">Liechtenstein</option> 
                <option value="Lithuania">Lithuania</option> 
                <option value="Luxembourg">Luxembourg</option> 
                <option value="Macao">Macao</option> 
                <option value="Macedonia, The Former Yugoslav Republic of">Macedonia, The Former Yugoslav Republic of</option> 
                <option value="Madagascar">Madagascar</option> 
                <option value="Malawi">Malawi</option> 
                <option value="Malaysia">Malaysia</option> 
                <option value="Maldives">Maldives</option> 
                <option value="Mali">Mali</option> 
                <option value="Malta">Malta</option> 
                <option value="Marshall Islands">Marshall Islands</option> 
                <option value="Martinique">Martinique</option> 
                <option value="Mauritania">Mauritania</option> 
                <option value="Mauritius">Mauritius</option> 
                <option value="Mayotte">Mayotte</option> 
                <option value="Mexico">Mexico</option> 
                <option value="Micronesia, Federated States of">Micronesia, Federated States of</option> 
                <option value="Moldova, Republic of">Moldova, Republic of</option> 
                <option value="Monaco">Monaco</option> 
                <option value="Mongolia">Mongolia</option> 
                <option value="Montenegro">Montenegro</option>
                <option value="Montserrat">Montserrat</option> 
                <option value="Morocco">Morocco</option> 
                <option value="Mozambique">Mozambique</option> 
                <option value="Myanmar">Myanmar</option> 
                <option value="Namibia">Namibia</option> 
                <option value="Nauru">Nauru</option> 
                <option value="Nepal">Nepal</option> 
                <option value="Netherlands">Netherlands</option> 
                <option value="New Caledonia">New Caledonia</option> 
                <option value="New Zealand">New Zealand</option> 
                <option value="Nicaragua">Nicaragua</option> 
                <option value="Niger">Niger</option> 
                <option value="Nigeria">Nigeria</option> 
                <option value="Niue">Niue</option> 
                <option value="Norfolk Island">Norfolk Island</option> 
                <option value="Northern Mariana Islands">Northern Mariana Islands</option> 
                <option value="Norway">Norway</option> 
                <option value="Oman">Oman</option> 
                <option value="Pakistan">Pakistan</option> 
                <option value="Palau">Palau</option> 
                <option value="Palestinian Territory, Occupied">Palestinian Territory, Occupied</option> 
                <option value="Panama">Panama</option> 
                <option value="Papua New Guinea">Papua New Guinea</option> 
                <option value="Paraguay">Paraguay</option> 
                <option value="Peru">Peru</option> 
                <option value="Philippines">Philippines</option> 
                <option value="Pitcairn">Pitcairn</option> 
                <option value="Poland">Poland</option> 
                <option value="Portugal">Portugal</option> 
                <option value="Puerto Rico">Puerto Rico</option> 
                <option value="Qatar">Qatar</option> 
                <option value="Reunion">Reunion</option> 
                <option value="Romania">Romania</option> 
                <option value="Russian Federation">Russian Federation</option> 
                <option value="Rwanda">Rwanda</option> 
                <option value="Saint Barthelemy">Saint Barthelemy</option> 
                <option value="Saint Helena, Ascension and Tristan da Cunha">Saint Helena, Ascension and Tristan da Cunha</option> 
                <option value="Saint Kitts and Nevis">Saint Kitts and Nevis</option> 
                <option value="Saint Lucia">Saint Lucia</option> 
                <option value="Saint Martin (French part)">Saint Martin (French part)</option> 
                <option value="Saint Pierre and Miquelon">Saint Pierre and Miquelon</option> 
                <option value="Saint Vincent and The Grenadines">Saint Vincent and The Grenadines</option> 
                <option value="Samoa">Samoa</option> 
                <option value="San Marino">San Marino</option> 
                <option value="Sao Tome and Principe">Sao Tome and Principe</option> 
                <option value="Saudi Arabia">Saudi Arabia</option> 
                <option value="Senegal">Senegal</option> 
                <option value="Serbia">Serbia</option> 
                <option value="Seychelles">Seychelles</option> 
                <option value="Sierra Leone">Sierra Leone</option> 
                <option value="Singapore">Singapore</option> 
                <option value="Sint Maarten (Dutch part)">Sint Maarten (Dutch part)</option> 
                <option value="Slovakia">Slovakia</option> 
                <option value="Slovenia">Slovenia</option> 
                <option value="Solomon Islands">Solomon Islands</option> 
                <option value="Somalia">Somalia</option> 
                <option value="South Africa">South Africa</option> 
                <option value="South Georgia and The South Sandwich Islands">South Georgia and The South Sandwich Islands</option> 
                <option value="South Sudan">South Sudan</option> 
                <option value="Spain">Spain</option> 
                <option value="Sri Lanka">Sri Lanka</option> 
                <option value="Sudan">Sudan</option> 
                <option value="Suriname">Suriname</option> 
                <option value="Svalbard and Jan Mayen">Svalbard and Jan Mayen</option> 
                <option value="Swaziland">Swaziland</option> 
                <option value="Sweden">Sweden</option> 
                <option value="Switzerland">Switzerland</option> 
                <option value="Syrian Arab Republic">Syrian Arab Republic</option> 
                <option value="Taiwan, Province of China">Taiwan, Province of China</option> 
                <option value="Tajikistan">Tajikistan</option> 
                <option value="Tanzania, United Republic of">Tanzania, United Republic of</option> 
                <option value="Thailand">Thailand</option> 
                <option value="Timor-leste">Timor-leste</option> 
                <option value="Togo">Togo</option> 
                <option value="Tokelau">Tokelau</option> 
                <option value="Tonga">Tonga</option> 
                <option value="Trinidad and Tobago">Trinidad and Tobago</option> 
                <option value="Tunisia">Tunisia</option> 
                <option value="Turkey">Turkey</option> 
                <option value="Turkmenistan">Turkmenistan</option> 
                <option value="Turks and Caicos Islands">Turks and Caicos Islands</option> 
                <option value="Tuvalu">Tuvalu</option> 
                <option value="Uganda">Uganda</option> 
                <option value="Ukraine">Ukraine</option> 
                <option value="United Arab Emirates">United Arab Emirates</option> 
                <option value="United Kingdom">United Kingdom</option> 
                <option value="United States">United States</option> 
                <option value="United States Minor Outlying Islands">United States Minor Outlying Islands</option> 
                <option value="Uruguay">Uruguay</option> 
                <option value="Uzbekistan">Uzbekistan</option> 
                <option value="Vanuatu">Vanuatu</option> 
                <option value="Venezuela, Bolivarian Republic of">Venezuela, Bolivarian Republic of</option> 
                <option value="Viet Nam">Viet Nam</option> 
                <option value="Virgin Islands, British">Virgin Islands, British</option> 
                <option value="Virgin Islands, U.S.">Virgin Islands, U.S.</option> 
                <option value="Wallis and Futuna">Wallis and Futuna</option> 
                <option value="Western Sahara">Western Sahara</option> 
                <option value="Yemen">Yemen</option> 
                <option value="Zambia">Zambia</option> 
                <option value="Zimbabwe">Zimbabwe</option>
    </select>
```

This is the data appeded dynamically to the div but the data is too long the white screen comes in android phone as well as in the emulator too so can any one help to solve this problem :(

Comment: Does the problem still occur if you use the dropdown menu native to Android (`data-native-menu="true"`)?

Comment: Yes and the issue is the large data so can we make it scroll

Comment: if i use data-native-menu="true" it is not working

Comment: I retagged your question `[android]` in case users in this tag can provide more insight. It would probably help if you specify the version of Android your device is running.

Comment: I dont think so anyone can fix this problem